# TimeSeparator for fo-FO culture in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, localization, datetime-format

I've instantiated the `CultureInfo` class with `fo-FO` (Faroese Island) culture.  However, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator` is showing as: (colon) not . (dot). How to fix this error?

Below is the code:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fo-FO");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

output

```
26-06-2012 15:15:17
```

Surprisingly, Time stamp alone is  not converted , but it did converted Date part.

By setting the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = "."` will solve the problem. But we are supporting multiple `culture` so i dont think it is a good idea to set `TimeSeparator`.

any pointer at the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ToString("T") to generate the full time, it will use periods instead of colons for fo-FO.